# Show that $L^1\subsetneq (L^\infty)^*$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

How does one show that $L^1\subsetneq (L^\infty)^*$? I am having trouble in this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711489/show-that-l-infty-is-strictly-contained-in-l1?rq=1 (see answer, don't look in title of question)

Comment: @Cortizol Thanks!

Comment: No problem. But that is also your question, so I am little bit confused. But if this is helpful I am glad to hear that.

Comment: very sorry, misread the question! :(

Answer (score 3):

This is a very standard and yet elegant proof.

We shall create a bounded linear functional on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, which is not realized by any element of $\ell^1(\mathbb N) $, using the [Hahn-Banach Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem).

Let first $c(\mathbb N)$ be the set of converging sequences. Clearly $c(\mathbb N)$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$. Let $u=\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\in c(\mathbb N)$. 
It is readily seen that the functional 
$$
\varphi(u)=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n, \quad \varphi : c(\mathbb N)\to \mathbb R,
$$ 
is a bounded linear functional of $c(\mathbb N)$, and in fact $\|\varphi\|=1$.

Using Hahn-Banach we can extend it to a bounded linear functional $\tilde\varphi$ on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, and with the same norm.

We shall show that $\tilde\varphi$ can not be realized by any element of $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$. Assume there is an $v=\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, such that
$$
\tilde\varphi(u)=\langle u,v\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_nv_n,
$$
Setting $$u^n=(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{n\,\,\text{zeros}},1,1,\ldots),
$$
then 
$$
\langle u^n,v\rangle=\sum_{k=n}^\infty v_k, \quad\text{and hence}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle u^n,v\rangle=0.
$$
However, $\tilde\varphi(u^n)=1$, since the limit of each sequence $u^n$ is equal to 1. Thus $\tilde\varphi$ is not representable by any element of $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: I think this isn't answer for this question.

Comment: @Cortizol: What do you mean?

Comment: It's something wrong with site I would say. I am on question "Show that $L^1\subsetneq (L^\infty)^*$", but in link it is `.....show-that-l1-subsetneq-l-infty`. I really don't know. I am confused.

Comment: I was looking at site and I think this is answer for this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717827/show-that-mathcall-infty-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mathcall1?lq=1. Again, maybe this is only for me, but I see your answer on question about $L^1$ etc and not $\ell^1$